# d3 table append data according to different data types

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table

When I have a data which includes several data types: data :`[a(string),b(number),c(array)]`
And I want to use d3 to put this data into a table. And I use

```
var td=d3.select("tr").selectAll("td").data(data).enter().append("td")
       .html(function(d){
           if(typeof(d)=='number') return ...
           if(typeof(d)=='number') return ...
       })
```

But I want to tell the type of the data before I append it to the table. How can I do with it? Can I do the if condition before the .html according to the function(d)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to first [`filter` your selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter) before setting the HTML:

```
var td=d3.select("tr").selectAll("td")
       .data(data).enter()
       .append("td")
       .filter(function(d){ return typeof(d) == 'number'; })
       .html(...)
```

Comment: It seems using filter just filter the results. I want to do different functions with different type of cells. When I use the filter it seems that I cannot combine the result.

Comment: Got it, just add filters after an append then it combines the results.